# Opencv 3.0.0 alpha with Cuda 6.5 , CudaStereo Error (Visual Studio 2013 x64)

Tags: opencv, cuda

when I try to compile the cudastereo project I receive 40 errors like this:

```
Error   46  error : calling a __host__ function("fmin<int, float> ") from a __global__ function("cv::cuda::device::stereocsbp::init_data_cost<short, (int)1> ") is not allowed  D:\ImageProcessing\GPU\opencv\sources\modules\cudastereo\src\cuda\stereocsbp.cu 219 opencv_cudastereo   1
```

would you please help me.
by the way all other cuda projects in opencv compiles successfully, and this is the exact function I need in opencv which is not compiling.

I believe the problem is in calling these functions:

```
        template<>  __device__ __forceinline__ static float pixeldiff<1>(const uchar* left, const uchar* right, float max_data_term)
    {
        return fmin( ::abs((int)*left - *righ), max_data_term);
    }
    template<>  __device__ __forceinline__ static float pixeldiff<3>(const uchar* left, const uchar* right, float max_data_term)
    {
        float tb = 0.114f * ::abs((int)left[0] - right[0]);
        float tg = 0.587f * ::abs((int)left[1] - right[1]);
        float tr = 0.299f * ::abs((int)left[2] - right[2]);

        return fmin(tr + tg + tb, max_data_term);
    }
    template<> __device__ __forceinline__ static float pixeldiff<4>(const uchar* left, const uchar* right, float max_data_term)
    {
        uchar4 l = *((const uchar4*)left);
        uchar4 r = *((const uchar4*)right);

        float tb = 0.114f * ::abs((int)l.x - r.x);
        float tg = 0.587f * ::abs((int)l.y - r.y);
        float tr = 0.299f * ::abs((int)l.z - r.z);

        return fmin(tr + tg + tb, max_data_term);
    }
```

Comment: You should show you codes.

Comment: it's not my own code, its the opencv library. the problem is in stereocsbp.cu file. I didn't change anything in the original Opencv library.

Comment: then ask the author.

Comment: Change `fmin` to `fminf`.

Comment: thanks already managed to solve it. added float before parameter

Comment: why don't you post an answer indicating what you changed exactly in the code to get it to compile.  And it might be useful to report it to the maintainers of opencv

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the first function so I changed it to

```
        template<> __device__ __forceinline__ static float pixeldiff<1>(const uchar* left, const uchar* right, float max_data_term)
    {

        float  tempfloat = ::abs((int)*left - *right);
        return fmin( tempfloat, max_data_term);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

need remove static declaration

template<> **device** **forceinline**  float pixeldiff<1>(const uchar* left, const uchar* right, float max_data_term)
    {
.....